# Is it allowed to add a UITabBarItem that opens up Safari?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I want to add a UITabBarItem on the TabBar which when clicked opens up Safari instead of loading its corresponding tab. (Not UIWebView but the app goes to background and opens up Safari instead)

I already know how to do this, but I was wondering if this is allowed by Apple. I know they're OK with using the TabBarItem to trigger other actions such as opening a modal in the app, etc. However I am not sure if it's OK to open a safari.

I am just being cautious because I don't want it to get rejected for this and wait another week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be allowed.

**But**: it could lead to confusion amongst your users, because they would most likely not expect that touching an item on the TabBar leads to an app switch. I would rather open a webView and offer the additional possibility to open the page in Safari.

Comment: Is it ok to have an entire tab dedicated to UIWebView? I've been getting burned by approval process lately that I'm getting cautious about anything. The app is fully functional app that has two other tabs that are native. It would be ideal if I could embed a web page in the third tab (This tab is something I want to iterate on quickly so that's why i want to use web, so that it will be updated immediately when i update the website)

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm doing such and it is also allowed by Apple.

But, I would personally suggest to use **UIWebView**, over **Safari** navigation. Because it will create unhealthy user experience, where he/she requires to jump around to swith in-between **Safari** and App. Rather you can open the same link in **UIWebView**, which will kepp our user in app only.